# Why is python being slow? And how can I make it faster?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 # set grid size, M*N (row, col)
 M: int = 5
 N: int = 5

def moves(pos: tuple, dpos: tuple) -> tuple:
     return (pos[0] + dpos[0], pos[1] + dpos[1])


def check_neighbors(white_pos: tuple, black_pos: tuple) -> bool:
  stationary = white_pos
  up = (white_pos[0], white_pos[1] + 1)
  upper_right = (white_pos[0] + 1, white_pos[1] + 1)
  upper_left = (white_pos[0] - 1, white_pos[1] + 1)
  left = (white_pos[0] - 1, white_pos[1])
  right = (white_pos[0] + 1, white_pos[1])
  lower_left = (white_pos[0] - 1, white_pos[1] - 1)
  down = (white_pos[0], white_pos[1] - 1)
  lower_right = (white_pos[0] + 1, white_pos[1] - 1)

  if (black_pos == stationary) or (black_pos == up) or (black_pos == upper_right) or (black_pos == upper_left) or (black_pos == left) or (black_pos == right) or (black_pos == lower_left) or (black_pos == down) or (black_pos == lower_right):
    return True
else:
    return False
def run_sim():
 w_x0 = random.sample([i for i in range(0,M)], 1)
 w_y0 = random.sample([j for j in range(0,N)], 1)

 b_x0 = random.sample([i for i in range(0,M)], 1)
 b_y0 = random.sample([j for j in range(0,N)], 1)


 white = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(w_x0, w_y0)]
 black = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(b_x0, b_y0)]
 stop: bool = False
 n: int = 0
 t: int = 0
 while stop != True:
    if check_neighbors(white[n], black[n]) == True:
        stop = True
    else:
        dt_w = random.sample([i for i in range(-1,2)], 2)
        dt_bl = random.sample([i for i in range(-1,2)], 2)
        white.append(moves(white[n], dt_w))
        black.append(moves(black[n], dt_bl))
        t = t+1
        n = n+1
 return n

  t_dist = [run_sim() for i in range(100)]
  print(t_dist)
```

excuse the terrible formatting

when it gets to t_dist = [run_sim() for i in range(100)] it takes FOREVER to run (I mean like wayy over 60 seconds). How can I get it to run faster and get my results? Why is it so computationally expensive?

I am using a jupyter notebook. I also tried just plain running it as a .py file and it is still slow. I tried using the debugger and after setting a breakpoint at t_dist = , it only shows a few iterations and then stops. If I set it to range(5), it works just fine but starts spazzing with bigger numbers (i.e. 100, 10000), which is what I want to run the simulation as.

Comment: We cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: You haven't said anything about what your code is supposed to do, or how it is supposed to do it.

Comment: updated code for reproduction

Comment: There may be ways to increase performance, but others have pointed out, you're not really explaining what you want done. That being said, try using pypy3 it generally runs 2-8 times faster

Comment: Python is bad at many simple loops. If you do the same thing, c++ is better.

Comment: have you tried replacing random.sample(1 digit from range lis) to `samplelist=[i for i in range(1,m)]` (as a setup variable) and then only use `random.sample(samplelist,1)` or even better, just `random.randint(1,m)`
i think forcing new for loops and sampling that loop and shrinking it to 1 digit is way more intensive. simply put you are generating the entire list, and randomizing it's order, and then shrinking it to length 1. which is super touch. You also may be getting a ton of repeat characters, and restarting your while loop too many times. try with m=10000 to see if it's crowding issues.

Comment: I would investigate what is happening in the ```check_neighbors(white[n], black[n])``` function. In some cases the ```while stop != True:```` loop will run run for over 500,000 iterations which I am guessing is not intended

Comment: I think his minimum size loop is causing the huge iterations @fthomson - i completely agree

Comment: From my read, there's no guarantee that `run_sim` will ever terminate. It looks to be mathematically equivalent to selecting two random numbers between 1 and 25 and returning the loop counter if the absolute value of their difference is 4 or less.

Comment: @RobertCotterman I agree. This one trial sometimes takes very long time logically, so it is realistic to define maximum of `n`

Comment: add a count+=1 measure inside the `while stop != True:` loop. Then have it print the count after the loop, and see how many times each one is running. I'd venture to guess some are 100's of thousands or even millions of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know only the distribution, you should define `max_t` and please adjust the value.

```py
def check_neighbors(a,b):
    return abs(a[0]-b[0]) + abs(a[1]-b[1]) <= 1 or\
 (abs(a[0]-b[0])==1 and abs(a[1]-b[1])==1)
def moves(a,b):
    return (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1])
def run_sim(M=5, N=5, max_t=10**6):
    w_co = [random.randrange(0,M), random.randrange(0,N)]# to produce random integer, you can use randrange
    b_co = [random.randrange(0,M), random.randrange(0,N)]

    t: int = 0
    while t<max_t:
        if check_neighbors(w_co, b_co) is True: # for bool, `is True` is strict
            break
        else:
            dt_w = [random.randrange(-1,2) for _ in range(2)]
            dt_b = [random.randrange(-1,2) for _ in range(2)]
            w_co=moves(w_co, dt_w)
            b_co=moves(b_co, dt_b)
            t+=1
            if (t%(max_t//20)==0):
                print(f"\t{t}") # check if the program is processing or not
    return t

t_dist = []
for i in range(100):
    if (i%10==1):
        print(i) # check the process
    t_dist.append(run_sim(M=5, N=5, max_t=10**6))
print(t_dist)
```

Additionally, this is a histogram of exapmle.
The graph shows some cases take very, very long time.

[image]